# Day of Yosef’s Sale

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, fast-days, historical-figures, yosef

I saw in a medrash - but can’t recall where - that the brothers sold Yosef on the tenth of Teveis.

Does any which medrash I could find this in?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, you didn't see it in a traditional "Midrash", since I've researched it pretty seriously and haven't come up with anything.

However, in a fairly recent "Midrash", a book of Derashot by [Rabbi Shlomo Fischer](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8), "Derashot Beit Yishai" (page 242, in Siman #30, which is his Derashah for the 10th of Tevet; [Otzar Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiigNKMnJLuAhXrYN8KHTSCCIUQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftablet.otzar.org%2Fen%2Fbook%2Fbook.php%3Fbook%3D25908%26width%3D0%26scroll%3D0%26udid%3D0%26page%3DP0147&usg=AOvVaw1zhF5zB8XTDo08lDZbEfCr)), he makes this suggestion. **He himself notes that it hasn't been said before:**

> ואילו מכירת יוסף לא פירש באיזה יום היה ולולי דמסתפינא אמינא שהיה ביום עשרה בטבת

He develops this idea with a couple of hints and other connection, as have various modern authors (a Google search in Hebrew can easily confirm this). Also important to consider is that the Parshiyot detailing the sale of Yoseph are read just before the 10th of Tevet.

This connection is cited by a few authors after him, sometimes with attribution e.g. [here](https://www.yutorah.org/download.cfm?materialID=537479), and sometimes just as a fact, e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2o5j7nJLuAhVlTd8KHTWtCY84ChAWMAB6BAgDEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ou.org%2Fnews%2Frabbis_weinreb_and_goldin_call_for_harmony_on_asara_btevet_webcast%2F&usg=AOvVaw047UI-k6twi4Wv8vCPXthf).

Answer (score -1):

Some posit that Yosef's sale by his brothers, occurred on Yom Kippur.

See Hebrew discussion here:
https://simla.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=16134

Comment: Can you summarize what they say.

Comment: @robev In my now-deleted answer to this question (which, having updated it recently, is what bumped this up and later prompted its deletion), I brought two sources that connect the sale to Yom Kippur: Moreh Nevochim, which merely ties the two together and the Book of Jubilees, which is what is mentioned in the forum post, which explicitly says the sale was on the tenth of the seventh month (Yom Kippur).

Comment: @Harel13 perhaps worth undeleting yours.

Comment: @Israel this isn't a midrash, nor a source for the claim that the OP mentioned, so I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Now I'm confused. I deleted it because you rightly pointed out that it doesn't answer what the OP is looking for...

Comment: @Harel13 I didn't realize that many others would do the same thing; at least yours was well-written and could deter others from posting similar answers (and some people might upvote it).

Comment: @רבות and Harel I'm not really following all this but it may be worth slightly generalizing the question https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759 to allow all the relevant info to be here on the same page

Comment: @DoubleAA Wouldn't that depend on the OP?

Comment: @DoubleAA and the fact that I placed a bounty on the question as is, not a broader version?